# Creating account.move by code - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm new into the `account.account` model of Odoo.

I wonder, is there some example on how to create an `account.move` on Odoo v8? (New API)

For example, suppose I have these models:

```
class model1(models.Model):

    field1 = fields.Float(string="Field 3")
    field2 = fields.Float(string="Field 3")
    field3 = fields.Float(string="Field 3", compute="compute") 
    partner_journal = fields.Many2one('account.account', string="Journal")
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('awaitingraw','Awaiting raw materials'),
        ('work_in_progress','Print in Progress'),
        ('delivered','Delivered'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string="State")
    csheet = fields.One2many('model2', 'sheets', string="Sheets")

    @api.depends('field1','field2','field3')
    def compute(self):
        if self.field1 or self.field2:
            self.field3 = self.field1 + self.field2

class model2(models.Model):

    field4 = fields.Float(string="Field 4")
    field5 = fields.Float(string="Field 5")
    field6 = fields.Float(string="Field 6")
    sheets = fields.Many2one('model1', string="Sheets")
```

From `model2` I need to create an `account.move` into a journal, let's say, I need `field3` should be the `credit` on whatever journal is selected on `partner_journal` field.

I've tried something like this:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'state', 'csheet')
def accounting_scenarios(self):
    for record in self:
        if not len(record.partner_journal):
            raise Warning('Please Enter Journal !')
        if record.state in ('awaitingraw'):
            record.partner_journal.debit = record.csheets.field4
```

But, it obviously doesn't works, because we need to create an `account.move` and with this method, what I was trying was to write directly on `partner_journal` on `debit` field, the `field4` quantity.

So, I'll need to create an `account.move` to make it work.

Any example or ideas?

Comment: call create method of model account.move from your module after pass all required argument and then call its write method to write this data in your db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you asking is not that easy you need to learn accounting module of Odoo and how Odoo handle accounting.

So first of all i recommend you to read Book "**Working with Odoo**" there is a small chapter that will give you a very good idea about account module.

Than see the codes in Odoo modules Ex: when you confirm a `sale.order` and how Odoo create a `account.move` that contains two `move.line`.

You will understand what is `account.account` and `account.move` and `account.move.line` , `journal entry`.

But the general idea : you need to create an `acount.move` and his `account.move.line`.

In `account.move` you need to specify what journal this transation are related to and some other useful information.
   In `account.move.line` this where you define all data related to the transaction. currency, partner(if There is one), account, debit and credit.

Same example Odoo 8.0:

```py
      # List of move.line 
      move_lines = [
                    (0, 0, {
                        'name': libelle, # a label so accountant can understand where this line come from
                        'debit': self_debit, # amount of debit
                        'credit': self_credit, # amount of credit
                        'account_id': account_id, # account 
                        'date': date,
                        'partner_id': partner_id, # partner if there is one
                        'currency_id': currency_id or (account.currency_id.id or False),
                    }),
                    (0, 0, {
                        'name': libelle,
                        'debit': debit, 
                        'credit': credit,
                        'account_id': writeoff_acc_id,
                        'analytic_account_id': context.get('analytic_id', False),
                        'date': date,
                        'partner_id': partner_id,
                        'currency_id': currency_id or (account.currency_id.id or False),
                    })
                ]

        # Create account move
        self.pool.get('account.move').create(cr, uid, {
                        'period_id': period_id, #Fiscal period
                        'journal_id': journal_id, # journal ex: sale journal, cash journal, bank journal....
                        'date':date,
                        'state': 'draft',
                        'line_id': move_lines, # this is one2many field to account.move.line
                    })
```

Comment: Thank You so much, for an awesome explanation, so, for every state on the document I should do something like this right?

Comment: You need to define witch account are touched by the operation, witch account is credited and witch account is debited because the goal of account is when you some all amount in all account will get Zero.

Comment: but don't do this in a compute field use buttons for example to validate or workflows you don't need to recreate the account.move multiple times

Comment: thank you, where to find the source code that writes on acount.move when validating a WH transfert ?